# How do I add a git repository to a vs2015 project?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2015

I'm pulling my hair out trying to create a vs2015 ASP.NET WebAPI project based around this git repository:
https://github.com/start-angular/SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-2

I've downloaded the zip.  But exactly where do I put the files?  In the project root or in the wwwRoot sub folder?

Can anyone point me straight?

Nick

Comment: Is the git repo your wanting to use a web site/app - I think it's just a web app programmed in typescript.  You can't really use a website inside of a Web API project.  A Web API project is meant for http services (no gui).

Comment: I should be able to.  It's common to have an angular UI in a web project with a webapi backend.  Regardless, I'd be happy just to get the git repository running in any kind of VS2015 project.